# debugging segmentation fault

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

I have a c++ program that compiles fine under gcc (4.8.1), icpc (13.1.3), clang++ (3.3) and runs okay except for the clang++ version which crashes with segfault. When I try to run this in the gdb or lldb debugger, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with address 0x0. The crash occurs in a member function of a helper class and the debugger claims that `this` has value `0x0`. However going up one level, the pointer `pimpl` of the helper class is reported to have a non-null value and I can access its data, which look perfectly sensible.

here is some pseudo code (`...` is not the ellipse, but means "some parameters")

```
struct helper;

struct foo {
  helper* pimpl;
  foo(...);
  void bar(...);
};

struct helper {
  helper(...);
  void hbar(...)
  {
     // crash here with *this = 0x0 according to debugger
  }
};

foo::foo(...) : pimpl(new helper(...)) {}

void foo::bar(...)
{
  pimpl->hbar(...);  // pimpl NOT 0x0 according to debugger ??!
}
```

What could have gone wrong and **how can I find out?** Note: the question is **NOT:** *"what is wrong with my code?"*

**edit 1** Perhaps it is worth mentioning that some of the arguments passed to `helper::hbar()` have been "optimised away by the compiler", according to the debugger, at the point of `foo::bar()`), while they have address `0x0` within `helper::hbar()`

**edit 2** If I print out the value of `this` from within `helper::hbar()` the error does not occur.

**edit 3** The error occurs with `-O0` as well as `-O2`.

**edit 4** The first arg of `helper::hbar()` was taken via `const` reference. If I change that to by value, everything works fine .... That argument was a spatial vector, similar to `std::array<double,3>`.

Comment: I'm grasping at straws here, but one suspect is copy behavior. Do you have a copy constructor and copy assignment operator defined for `foo`, or copying disabled?

Comment: I think an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would help. I can't see anything obviously broken with your code.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. I have edited the question to be clearer what my question actually is.

Comment: Are you compiling without optimizations? Debuggers will often output nonsensical results if you attempt to debug an optimized build.

Comment: `this` being `0` in a debugger is not uncommon for optimized member function calls. It would be interesting to see the exact line inside `helper::hbar` that crashes.

Comment: Double-check all your copy/move/assignment thingies (& destructors). `valgrind` may help sometimes. clang's sanitizers too maybe.

Comment: Can we see the code around where you call foo::bar()? Are there any copies/moves happening beforehand?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker it crashes right at the entry to the member function. Also trying to print any argument to this member function (`hbar()` in my pseudo code) results in *cannot access memory at address 0x0*.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it - create a log file, print value of pimpl/some variable belonging to pimpl before

```
pimpl->hbar(...);,
```

and inside

```
pimpl->hbar(...);
```

Compare output from different compilers, try narrow down the problem that way adding more output to log file as you start seeing divergence...

Comment: I guess, it would be helpful to see the actual contents of hbar(). If you just put line (*this); inside hbar(), would the error still occur?